# Is it a bad idea to register domains

Tags: domains

...with the same registrar?

Should I register each domain with a different registrar? Like `domain.com` on godaddy, `domain.org` on name.com etc.

So in case one registrar steals your domain, you still have the other domains

Comment: Why in the world would you think this?

Comment: i don't know. just asking...

Comment: Which shady $0.50 per domain registrar are you planning on using? Well known registrars would not stay in business doing this, word would get out and they'd lose their business as people transferred their domains to other domain registrars. It's more important that you keep your login credentials safe so they don't get hijacked by someone else.

Comment: not $0.5, but I was thinking of namecheap.com. It says on their site they register domains for $3 :)

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely unlikely major registrars will steal your domain names. Many of the 'claims' about this happening online are down to people ignoring the reminder emails and losing their domains.

So yes, it's a bad idea to register each domain with a different provider, if for no other reason than it's an administrative nightmare.